# Logging Unique Request IDs in text file NLog - To differentiate between requests

Tags: logging, nlog

I am using NLog logging mechanism in my application. The problem I face is when concurrent requests hit the application logging is done asynchronously and I am not able to identify which line belongs to which request. Is there a way in NLog to set the configuration to NLog itself logging a unique Request ID for each request ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
<targets>    
<!-- add your targets here -->
<target xsi:type="File" name="file"    fileName="E:\IBELogs\AirAvailability\AirAvailability.log" layout="${longdate}        ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />    
</targets>
<rules>
<!-- add your logging rules here --> 
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />    
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to generate your unique ID yourself. Then you can set the unique ID into the [MDC](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_MDC.htm) and set the appropriate layout format that outputs your unique from MDC into the log.

Comment: Thanks Wilx... As am a newbee could you please tell how to generate unique Request ID and set it to MDC ? Please

Answer (score 3):

In NLog 4.1 ${activityid} was introduced, see [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Trace-Activity-Id-Layout-Renderer). I cannot say [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.correlationmanager.activityid(v=vs.110).aspx) is clear enough about its value, but so far, this is doing the trick for us, since every request in our webAPI application gets assigned a unique GUID and it is preserved through the entire request as we see the same value in several Nlog operations in the same request.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Initialize `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` in the `Global.asax`

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

Step 2. Add ${activiryid} in the NLog.config

```
layout="${longdate}|${activityid}|${threadid}|${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite}|Line-${callsite-linenumber}|${message}"
```

Then the activityid in the log file can be treated as the request id.

Answer (score 2):

We faced a similar problem and we used the thread Id to identify the lines in the logfile. Therefore specify the layout like the following:

```
<target ... layout="threadID: ${threadid} ${message}"/>
```

If the concurrent requests differ in nature it may be a good idea to create multiple loggers, one for each request type. Then you can do something like this:

```
<target ... layout="logger: ${logger} ${message}"/>
```

I hope this helps.